# 403 forbidden on image url on production asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, iis-7

I've referred lots of site and questions, but did not find any solution. It is working on my local site but not on production.
Structure:

```
-Root
 -Files
  -Products
   -Product01.jpg
 -others
   -Product01.jpg
```

I'm able to access `Product01.jpg` from others folder, but when I'm trying to access image from `Products` it gives me an error of `403 forbidden:You have attempted to view a resource that does not have Read access.`.
I've Added `IUSer`, `IIS_IUser` and `NETWORK SERVICES` with full access. But getting same error.

Also tried with allow anonymous authentication, but no luck!

Side: All users roles have full permission.

Comment: Is this MVC application?

MVC automatically server static content from Content folder. You can refer you images in your application like this

    Url.Content("~/Content/Images/Image.jpg")

If you want to more configuration / cache settings etc you can configure your IIS to server your assets StaticHandler you can configure your web.config 

     <handlers>
      <add name="StaticHandler" verb="*" path="*.jpg" type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" />
    </handlers>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I got the answer.
I'm using IBM VPS server, So need configure as below.

`IIS` > `Folder` >  `Handler mappings`  > `Edit Feature Permissions` > check here is enabled or not! and checked `Read` and `Script`

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to add a location element to your web.config to allow access to specific files/folders

```
<location path="/Root/Files/Products"> 
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*"/> 
        </authorization>
     </system.web>
</location>
```

This should allow anonymous access to all files in the folder specified in the location path attribute

Answer (score 0):

If this is your Root Folder:

> Manually Write click your root folder > Properties > Security Tab >  Click Edit button > select user >
>   full control

Good luck